# Validation Class not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

I am using symfony2 validator component. I have downloaded zip files from pear.symfony.com. Unzipped files and now my directory structure is as following.

-Symfony
-index.php

---

`index.php` has following code to just test that validation class is being included.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validateValue('Bernhard', new Length(array('min' => 10)));

?>
```

But getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation' not found in  
C:\xampp\htdocs\labeeb-projects\testing symfony2 components\index.php on line 10
```

Comment: 1) PEAR is deprecated, use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/); 2) you forgot to autoload/load the classes

Comment: Actually, PEAR is alive and well and in no way depreciated.  Composer is easier especially since it generates an autoload file for you.

Comment: @Cerad He said deprecated, not depreciated :), has a slightly different meaning. But yes, I'd also recommend composer.